# JFileChooser delivers file name as null

Tags: java, string, swing, file, jfilechooser

I've been writing an audio/video converter in Java. Everything is working smoothly, except for the JFileChooser. (I use AWT FileDialog usually for choosing files but can't use it in this project because I've heard FileDialog is OS Dependent-please advise.)

Here's how my File selection process works:

- I've defined a public String fileLocn. fileLocn will contain the location of the file selected.
- My program uses Swing. There is a JButton which will open the JFIleChooser, called FilePicker. Here is the code for the FilePicker as follows:

  ```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  JFileChooser FilePicker=new JFileChooser();
  int returnVal = FilePicker.showOpenDialog(this);
  if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file=FilePicker.getSelectedFile();
  formatpanel.setEnabled(true);
  fileLocn=FilePicker.getCurrentDirectory().toString()+"\\"+FilePicker.getName();
  filelocation.setText(fileLocn);
  }
  ```
- The FilePicker selects the file and supplies it's location to the string fileLocn, which is used as the location for another file. Please note that the filelocation TextField is ornamental and not used in the main code.

This is where the problem arises. The getCurrentDirectory() command is working correctly, but the getName() command is being delivered as null. So, if I select a file FQSEMI.mp4 in the "Videos" folder of my C: drive, it is shown as C:\Videos\null rather than the desired C:\Videos\FQSEMI.

Please point out what is wrong with my code. Thank you.

(P.S. Guaranteed upvote to relevant answers and I'll mention you in the credits :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the `name` property of the `JFileChooser` instead of the file that was selected...

Instead of...

```
fileLocn=FilePicker.getCurrentDirectory().toString()+"\\"+FilePicker.getName()
```

You'll find...

```
fileLocn=file.getPath();
```

Will do what you want - in a platform neutral way...remember, only Windows uses `\` as the separator, doing this on Mac or Unix based systems will cause not end of issues.  If you really must supply the separator, you can use `/` on Windows, but it's normally better to use `File.separator`

**Updated based on comments**

Basically, you need to extract the name from the extension, you can do something like..

```
String fileWithoutExt = fileLocn.substring(0, fileLocn.indexOf("."));
```

While will strip off everything after the last `.` including the last `.`

So, if you have a `String` with the value of `FQSEMI.mp4`, it will return `FQSEMI`

Comment: Another question: The file created is being labeled as FQSEMI.mp4.flv. How do I name it simply as FQSEMI.flv?

Comment: Are you modifying the name after you get from the `JFileChooser`?  If so how?

Comment: This is what is happening:
Your getFile Command gets me the path, which is then stored in fileLocn. I have another string format which assigns a format to the video.
Now I have two files:
File src=new File(fileLocn); and File trgt=new File(fileLocn+format);
How do i stop the FilePicker to convey it's extension to the final title ie. final file should be FQSEMI.flv, not FQSEMI.mp4.flv

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)

Comment: And another thing: You're modifying fileLocn. I don't want fileLocn to be modified, so i built a new string called filex which extracts the filename for me.

Comment: Then your `String` doesn't contain a `.`...you can use `String#contains` to check this...

Comment: It does. Here's a fileLocn Output: C:\Videos\FQSEMI.mp4

Comment: Based on your error, the value you're using doesn't - also I updated the answer so it doesn't assign the value back to `fileLocn`

Comment: All problems solved :D . Please give me your real name so that I can include you in the credits. If you have a website/blog give me the link please!

Answer (score 1):

When you all `filePicker.getName()`, you are retrieving the name of the `JFileChooser` object itself.  Instead, you want the name of the selected file.  To get this, call `filePicker.getSelectedFile().getName()`.  Better yet, get the path of the file, rather than constructing the path by concatenating strings:

```
fileLocn = filePicker.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

(Note that in Java we tend to name variables starting with lower case characters in order to avoid confusion with classes.  This will also help syntax highlighters like the one used on this site.)